# How to import a module on level above?

Tags: python

In my project, I have the following folder structure:

```
myproject-with-hifens-not-my-fault
    |-- .venv
    |-- package_1
    |   |-- a.py
    |-- package_2
        |-- b.py
        |-- c.py
    |-- constants.py
```

In a.py, I try to do `from constants import ROOT_DIR`, however, I get the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'`

Is there a way of importing constants.py?

Note: ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))

Comment: `from constants import ROOTDIR` or `from ROOTDIR import constants`?

Comment: ROOT_DIR is a directory path, that I'll use when managing files in the project. So, from constants impor ROOT_DIR

Comment: What about `from .. import constants.ROOTDIR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you're calling `a.py` from.

If you're running it directly--i.e., entering `py a.py` in the command line or running the debugger straight from the `a.py` module --then you're going to have some trouble. You'll only be able to access modules within `package_1` and its children directories.

If you're running it from an entry point (e.g., if you were to have a `__main__.py` module in your root), then `from constants import ROOTDIR` will work just fine in `a.py`.

FYI, Real Python has a great [primer on imports](https://realpython.com/python-import/) that I'd recommend you check out for more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm running a.py directly... that's my problem. Btw, I've just read that primer. It's good, but I didn't find a solution to my problem there... :/

Comment: How are you intending the user to interact with the code? Could you refactor your code so that there's a `__main__.py` entrypoint?

Comment: By running a.py directly. This file is like a unit test, but without being run with a specific package like pytest...

Comment: If the user is interacting directly with `a.py`, that might mean it's the main script.

One way to think about it--if `a.py` imports `b.py`, that would mean that `b.py` should never import `a.py`. (Doing so would result in a circular import--bad news!) And that means `a.py` should be higher up in the architecture than either of the latter two.

As [this article](https://medium.com/@shivendraodean/software-architecture-the-onion-architecture-1b235bec1dec) observes, "Dependencies should be inward and never outward. Code should only depend on the same layer or layers more central to itself."